# Displaying a Rating Bar using Sql Lite database in Java

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, ratingbar

Hi im a new user trying to display a rating system using an SQL database. i can get the user to enter a name and rate, and this is saved to the database. but when i go to show everything in the database, it doesnt display the rating bar, it displayed "android.widget.RatingBar@41d0687"

If anyone could help me just display the rating bar that would be fantastic.
heres a copy of some of the code used.

```
  Button previousEntries, save, getinfo1, editT,deleteT;
    EditText date, diaryEntry,searchrow;
   public RatingBar placerating;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);



       searchrow = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText);
        date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etExProg);
        diaryEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEntry1);
        placerating = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);


        getinfo1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getinfo);
        editT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit);
        deleteT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);
        previousEntries = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previousentry1);
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save1);

        placerating.setOnClickListener(Test.this);
        deleteT.setOnClickListener(Test.this);
        editT.setOnClickListener(Test.this);
        getinfo1.setOnClickListener(this);
        previousEntries.setOnClickListener(this);
        save.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        //switch statement for different options
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.save1:

                    //get data from the edit text inputs
                    String theDate = date.getText().toString();
                    String dEntry = String.valueOf(placerating);

                    //create an instance of class Entries
                    Entries entry = new Entries(Test.this);
                    entry.open();

                    entry.createEntry(theDate, dEntry);
                    entry.close();



                        //once save is succesful move out to exercise programmes class
                        Intent i = new Intent(Test.this,ExerciseProgrammes.class );
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }

            case R.id.previousentry1:
                //if user selects all diary entries, show them.
                Intent i = new Intent(Test.this,SQLReader.class );
                startActivity(i);
                break;
```

And this is the class which sets up and saves the database. Thanks!

```
  //setting variable for the table
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_EXERCISE_ROUT = "exercise_routine";
public static final String KEY_EXERCISE_INFO = "personal_info";

//setting variables for the database, the name
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ProgressTracker";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "userTable";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;



//dbhelper class which set sup database
private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public DbHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    //first time dbhelper class called it goes here, and creates the table
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_EXERCISE_ROUT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_EXERCISE_INFO + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );
    }

    @Override
    //any other time dbhelper class called, it goes here and updates table
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i2)
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public Entries(Context c){ //class name
    ourContext = c;
}//Entries

public Entries open(){ //class name
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}//open

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}//close

//using the data passed in from parameters from exercisediary.class, insert data into table
public long createEntry(String theDate, String dEntry){
    //setting up new contentValues varibale
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    //cv.put method puts the info passed in from parameters in the cv variable
    cv.put(KEY_EXERCISE_ROUT, theDate);
    cv.put(KEY_EXERCISE_INFO, dEntry);
    //entering the new values into teh table
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}//CreateEntry

public String getData(){
    String [] columns = new String []{KEY_ROWID, KEY_EXERCISE_ROUT, KEY_EXERCISE_INFO};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    //setting variables for each column in the database that needs to be returned
    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EXERCISE_ROUT);
    int iInfo = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EXERCISE_INFO);

    for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
  result = result + c.getString(iRow)+ "."+c.getString(iDate)+c.getString(iInfo);             
    }                        

    //return result to print out for user to see
    return result;
}//getData
```

Answer (score 0):

A `RatingBar` object is not a string, and it does not make sense to try to convert it into one.

A rating bar *is* not a value, it *has* a value.
To get the value, call [getRating()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#getRating%28%29):

```
float dEntry = placerating.getRating();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are now doing is that you saving Object description in database. String.valueOf(Object); will return just human-readable description of this object. If you want to save value of rating bar, then you have to use getRating() method which will return the current rating in float.

Change these lines:

```
    entry.createEntry(theDate, placerating.getRating());

    public long createEntry(String theDate, float dEntry){
    }

    @Override
    //Change datatype to REAL
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_EXERCISE_ROUT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_EXERCISE_INFO + " REAL)"
        );
    }

public String getData(){

    float iInfo = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EXERCISE_INFO);
}
```